# Getting computer name in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I need to get the computer name using VBScript.

I tried

```
Set wshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Network" )
strComputerName = wshNetwork.ComputerName
WScript.Echo "Computer Name: " & strComputerName
```

But I got an error.

I can't figure out what the error is because I'm running the script from SecureCRT.

Does anyone know where this error is coming from ?

Thanks

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: @RomoDaneghyan i get a runtime error for the first line, if i add Dim wshNetwork, i get a object error

Comment: please post the error message here :)

Comment: @RomoDaneghyan nevermind it worked, VBScript has Wscript built in, so i just have to use CreateObject instead of Wscript.CreateObject()

Comment: It is good @Necro1992 :)